# Read a HashMap in App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, hashtable

I try to read my data on a Hash Table but I search in the internet but i don't find a solution.

```
 KPIs.push( {name: [data[0][j]], unite :[data[1][j]],  order: [data[2][j]], column:[j] , area:[getArea(data[0][j])] }  )    ;
```

I try :

```
KPIs.value["name"] // doesn't work 
KPIs.length // work
```

How can I read this HashTable ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: KPI is array of hashmaps. iterate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code it appears you are pushing an Object onto an Array, but you attempt to access the object properties directly on the Array, rather than on the element in the Array.

You'll first need to access the correct Array element, before attempting to access your object properties:

```
KPIs[0].name
```

or, to loop over them:

```
for(var i in KPIs){
   var name = KPIs[i].name;
   Logger.log(name);
}
```

See details on Arrays here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array